# Jython Classes can't be found

Tags: java, python, jython, pythoninterpreter

I wrote a java file named jug.java that uses jython and PythonInterpreter; this is the code:

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
import org.python.core.PyObject;

public class Jug{
    public void main(String[] args) {
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.exec("import InstaFeed\nAPI=InstaFeed.InstaFeed(someusername, somepassword)");
        PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("API.like(mediaId");
        PyObject result = someFunc.__call__(new PyInteger(15));
        String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
    }
}
```

when I try executing it using this command:

> javac Jug.java

These error occur:

```
Jug.java:1: error: package org.python.util does not exist
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
                      ^
Jug.java:2: error: package org.python.core does not exist
import org.python.core.PyObject;
                      ^
Jug.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        ^
  symbol:   class PythonInterpreter
  location: class Jug
Jug.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
                                            ^
  symbol:   class PythonInterpreter
  location: class Jug
Jug.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("like");
        ^
  symbol:   class PyObject
  location: class Jug
Jug.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        PyObject result = someFunc.__call__(new PyInteger(15));
        ^
  symbol:   class PyObject
  location: class Jug
Jug.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        PyObject result = someFunc.__call__(new PyInteger(15));
                                                ^
  symbol:   class PyInteger
  location: class Jug
7 errors
```

Also jython is installed.
How can I solve that error?

**MORE INFORMATION**

Already I have installed jython using terminal:

```
sudo apt install jython
```

It successfully installs jython.
But whenever I try to install it from source:

```
sudo java -jar jython-installer-2.7.0.jar
```

These error occur:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0f6e654009, pid=31088, tid=31089
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P" (or dumping to /home/muhammad/Downloads/core.31088)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/muhammad/Downloads/hs_err_pid31088.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: So did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

package org.python.util should exists in jython.jar that you are missing

You can download it from [jython](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html)

If it exists add it to your command (instead of `javac Jug.java`)

```
java -cp jython.jar:. Jug
```

Comment: Have you tried calling java -cp jython-installer-2.7.0.jar:. Jug?

Comment: Yes and output: Error: Could not find or load main class Jug

Comment: You should run in same folder as Jug.java

Comment: Yes I did it there

Comment: Your java file should be saved as Jug.java and not jug.java